# Where is CI_APPLICATION_TAG define in GItLab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new to GitLab Auto DevOps.

I encountered some environment variables which are "`CI_APPLICATION_TAG`"、"`CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY`"、"`CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG`".

> I can't find where their definitions are. Is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see them in action in [`gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-yml` issue 50](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-yml/issues/50)

> **The Docker image naming strategy** in Auto DevOps is defined via the `CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY` and `CI_APPLICATION_TAG` variables near the start of the auto_devops before_script.
>   The format differs from the way I name and tag images, but the inline export statements make it difficult to customize since the script itself has to be modified.
>
> ```
> export CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
> export CI_APPLICATION_TAG=$CI_COMMIT_SHA
> ```

Also, [`gitlab-org/gitlab-ce` issue 53129](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/53129)

> For building Docker images in a project, GitLab CI provides the predefined variable `CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE` that returns the base image name for images stored the Container Registry tied to the project.
>
> This can be be used in conjunction with `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` or `CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG` for the image tag.
>
> The [`Docker.gitlab-ci.yml` template demonstrates](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/cf291a110d0b8911a38764850d1a1d0f54b060c3/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml) this in its build job script.
>
> ```
> - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" .
> - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
> ```
>
> GitLab Auto DevOps declares two local variables in its before_script for the image name and tag.
>
> ```
> export CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
> export CI_APPLICATION_TAG=$CI_COMMIT_SHA
> ```

With:

> - `CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY` is used to define the image name, and
> - `CI_APPLICATION_TAG` for the image tag

Answer (score 2):

Snippet from https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Build.gitlab-ci.yml

```
      if [[ -z "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" ]]; then
        export CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY=${CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY:-$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
        export CI_APPLICATION_TAG=${CI_APPLICATION_TAG:-$CI_COMMIT_SHA}
      else
        export CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY=${CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY:-$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}
        export CI_APPLICATION_TAG=${CI_APPLICATION_TAG:-$CI_COMMIT_TAG}
      fi
```